# Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple' - Interesting error

Tags: python, list

I recieve an unexpected error for my code above "Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple'". I have researched on the internet for the solution but could not find it. It must be about definition but I could not find where the mistake is. Error is on Line 13. Appriciate your help.

```
from math import pow,sqrt

q=1
Nlist= [1,7,5,9,4,6,4,3,5,8,3,10,9]
aplist=[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]
bplist=[0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1]
cplist=[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]
dplist=[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
eplist=[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]
ajlist=[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(1,13,1):
    A=sqrt(pow((q*Nlist[0]/13-ajlist[0]-aplist[0]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[1]/13-ajlist[1]-aplist[1]),2)
    +pow((q*Nlist[2]/13-ajlist[2]-aplist[2]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[3]/13-ajlist[3]-aplist[3]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[4]/13-ajlist[4]-aplist[4]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[5]/13-ajlist[5]-aplist[5]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[6]/13-ajlist[6]-aplist[6]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[7]/13-ajlist[7]-aplist[7]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[8]/13-ajlist[8]-aplist[8]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[9]/13-ajlist[9]-aplist[9]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[10]/13-ajlist[10]-aplist[10]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[11]/13-ajlist[11]-aplist[11]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[12]/13-ajlist[12]-aplist[12]),2))

print("A'nın değeri:",A)


B=sqrt(pow((q*Nlist[0]/13-ajlist[0]-bplist[0]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[1]/13-ajlist[1]-bplist[1]),2)
+pow((q*Nlist[2]/13-ajlist[2]-bplist[2]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[3]/13-ajlist[3]-bplist[3]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[4]/13-ajlist[4]-bplist[4]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[5]/13-ajlist[5]-bplist[5]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[6]/13-ajlist[6]-bplist[6]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[7]/13-ajlist[7]-bplist[7]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[8]/13-ajlist[8]-bplist[8]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[9]/13-ajlist[9]-bplist[9]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[10]/13-ajlist[10]-bplist[10]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[11]/13-ajlist[11]-bplist[11]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[12]/13-ajlist[12]-bplist[12]),2))

print("B'nın değeri:",B)


C=sqrt(pow((q*Nlist[0]/13-ajlist[0]-cplist[0]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[1]/13-ajlist[1]-cplist[1]),2)
+pow((q*Nlist[2]/13-ajlist[2]-cplist[2]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[3]/13-ajlist[3]-cplist[3]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[4]/13-ajlist[4]-cplist[4]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[5]/13-ajlist[5]-cplist[5]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[6]/13-ajlist[6]-cplist[6]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[7]/13-ajlist[7]-cplist[7]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[8]/13-ajlist[8]-cplist[8]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[9]/13-ajlist[9]-cplist[9]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[10]/13-ajlist[10]-cplist[10]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[11]/13-ajlist[11]-cplist[11]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[12]/13-ajlist[12]-cplist[12]),2))

print("C'nın değeri:",C)


D=sqrt(pow((q*Nlist[0]/13-ajlist[0]-dplist[0]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[1]/13-ajlist[1]-dplist[1]),2)
+pow((q*Nlist[2]/13-ajlist[2]-dplist[2]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[3]/13-ajlist[3]-dplist[3]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[4]/13-ajlist[4]-dplist[4]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[5]/13-ajlist[5]-dplist[5]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[6]/13-ajlist[6]-dplist[6]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[7]/13-ajlist[7]-dplist[7]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[8]/13-ajlist[8]-dplist[8]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[9]/13-ajlist[9]-dplist[9]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[10]/13-ajlist[10]-dplist[10]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[11]/13-ajlist[11]-dplist[11]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[12]/13-ajlist[12]-dplist[12]),2))

print("D'nin değeri:",D)


E=sqrt(pow((q*Nlist[0]/13-ajlist[0]-eplist[0]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[1]/13-ajlist[1]-eplist[1]),2)
+pow((q*Nlist[2]/13-ajlist[2]-eplist[2]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[3]/13-ajlist[3]-eplist[3]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[4]/13-ajlist[4]-eplist[4]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[5]/13-ajlist[5]-eplist[5]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[6]/13-ajlist[6]-eplist[6]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[7]/13-ajlist[7]-eplist[7]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[8]/13-ajlist[8]-eplist[8]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[9]/13-ajlist[9]-eplist[9]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[10]/13-ajlist[10]-eplist[10]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[11]/13-ajlist[11]-eplist[11]),2)+
pow((q*Nlist[12]/13-ajlist[12]-eplist[12]),2))

print("E'nin değeri:",E)
q=q+1
list1=[A,B,C,D,E]
print(min(list1))


if(min(list1)==list1[0]):
    print("A atandı.")
elif(min(list1)==list1[1]):
    print("B atandı")

elif(min(list1)==list1[2]):
    print("C atandı")
   
elif(min(list1)==list1[3]):
    print("D atandı")
    
elif(min(list1)==list1[4]):
    print("E atandı")
  


if(min(list1)==list1[0]):
    ajlist[1]=ajlist[1]+1,
    ajlist[3]=ajlist[3]+1,
    ajlist[5]=ajlist[5]+1,
    ajlist[9]=ajlist[9]+1,
    ajlist[11]=ajlist[11]+1,
    ajlist[12]=ajlist[12]+1,
    print("geldim")
elif(min(list1)==list1[1]):
    ajlist[2]=ajlist[2]+1,
    ajlist[3]=ajlist[3]+1,
    ajlist[5]=ajlist[5]+1,
    ajlist[8]=ajlist[8]+1,
    ajlist[10]=ajlist[10]+1,
    ajlist[12]=ajlist[12]+1,
elif(min(list1)==list1[2]):
    ajlist[2]=ajlist[2]+1,
    ajlist[3]=ajlist[3]+1,
    ajlist[6]=ajlist[6]+1,
    ajlist[9]=ajlist[9]+1,
    ajlist[11]=ajlist[11]+1,
elif(min(list1)==list1[3]):
    ajlist[1]=ajlist[1]+1,
    ajlist[4]=ajlist[4]+1,
    ajlist[7]=ajlist[7]+1,
    ajlist[8]=ajlist[8]+1,
    ajlist[11]=ajlist[11]+1,
    ajlist[12]=ajlist[12]+1,
elif(min(list1)==list1[4]):
    ajlist[0]=ajlist[0]+1,
    ajlist[4]=ajlist[4]+1,
    ajlist[6]=ajlist[6]+1,
    ajlist[9]=ajlist[9]+1,
    ajlist[10]=ajlist[10]+1,
```

I recieve an unexpected error for my code above "Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple'". I have researched on the internet for the solution but could not find it. It must be about definition but I could not find where the mistake is. Error is on Line 13. Appriciate your help.

Comment: Why post 118 lines if the error is in line 13?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and there is no such error

Comment: It works for me. Could you post the full error message? And I'd like to repeat the question from  @ThomasWeller: "Why did you post so many lines?"

Comment: The code is a mess. Why calculate `A` 12 times and not even use `i` which is declared in the `for` loop?

Comment: @Matthias I'm so sorry, new to this site and programming. 
'File "<ipython-input-1-d6b0b12c295f>", line 13, in <module>
    +pow((q*Nlist[2]/13-ajlist[2]-aplist[2]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[3]/13-ajlist[3]-aplist[3]),2)+

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple' '

Comment: @ThomasWeller I was desperate to solve the problem. Trying to do it for 1 week, I broke the code a little bit I guess.

Comment: What Python version do you use?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I use Python 3.7 on Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can't reproduce the exact problem. However, your code is quite messy. It seems you were on the right track but failed to get it right. The code

```
for i in range(1,13,1):
    A=sqrt(pow((q*Nlist[0]/13-ajlist[0]-aplist[0]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[1]/13-ajlist[1]-aplist[1]),2)
    +pow((q*Nlist[2]/13-ajlist[2]-aplist[2]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[3]/13-ajlist[3]-aplist[3]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[4]/13-ajlist[4]-aplist[4]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[5]/13-ajlist[5]-aplist[5]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[6]/13-ajlist[6]-aplist[6]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[7]/13-ajlist[7]-aplist[7]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[8]/13-ajlist[8]-aplist[8]),2)+pow((q*Nlist[9]/13-ajlist[9]-aplist[9]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[10]/13-ajlist[10]-aplist[10]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[11]/13-ajlist[11]-aplist[11]),2)+
    pow((q*Nlist[12]/13-ajlist[12]-aplist[12]),2))
```

could be as short as

```
sum_of_powers = 0
for i in range(13):
    sum_of_powers += pow((q * Nlist[i] / 13 - ajlist[i] - aplist[i]), 2)
A = sqrt(sum_of_powers)
```

A similar thing repeats for `B`, so you should make it a function instead of copy/pasting the whole thing:

```
def root_of_powers(plist:list):
    sum_of_powers = 0
    for i in range(13):
        sum_of_powers += pow((q * Nlist[i] / 13 - ajlist[i] - plist[i]), 2)
    return sqrt(sum_of_powers)
```

And use it like

```
A = root_of_powers(aplist)
B = root_of_powers(bplist)
...
```

With all the duplicate code removed, it's a) much easier to spot mistakes and b) much easier to correct mistakes, because you don't need to correct it in all the copied places.

Comment: I've corrected my code as you said and got the same error. I pasted my code to an online compiler https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ still getting the same error. Can you help me please?

Comment: @sim: I copied the code into that online compiler and it runs without problems. Please make sure you copy the code that you posted on this site, not some other code. We can't help you if you use different code than posted here.

Comment: @sim: for the error to appear, the code must be something like `pow((q*Nlist[2]/13-(ajlist[2],)-aplist[2]),2)` or `pow((q*Nlist[2]/13-(ajlist[2],aplist[2])),2)`. Note the additional braces and commas